# what are on my fig tree leaves

Tags: identification, figs

[image]Hi I’m in the uk and the leaves of my potted fig tree are shrivelling open and dying. On them are thousands of tiny black dots protected under a clear film. I don’t know what they are and whether to brush them off or leave them be. And if the fig tree can be saved? Thanks

Comment: What type of fig? Can you add a photo please?

Comment: Hi it’s a ficus carica. Just trying to work out how to do photos!